# android network connection faliure

Tags: java, android, network-programming, android-manifest

I'm having a hard time to connect the application to the internet and retrieve the html source.
Been looking all over for a solution and didn't find. Hope someone could help.
Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    URL url=null;
                    url = new URL(et.getText().toString());
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        tv.append(line);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        });
    }
```

I've also added INTERNET permission..

Comment: What happens? doesn't it compile? Does it give exception? What does it print on logcat?

Comment: Internet request shouldn't be in Main Thread.

Comment: readLine method is potentially blocking the thread. You should make this in its own thread.

Comment: You cannot make the internet request on main Thread(UI)

Comment: Just One thing is remember that You can't Update your UI on main thread....And for solution you have to use Async class or you can use Thread...

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the code which connects to the internet and fetches data to an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This is because of the `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

Though there is a workaround available by using the `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy`, it highly advisable not to do that.

Here is a excerpt from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).

**NetworkOnMainThreadException:-**

> This is only thrown for applications
>   targeting the Honeycomb SDK or higher. Applications targeting earlier
>   SDK versions are allowed to do networking on their main event loop
>   threads, but it's heavily discouraged.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/2024761) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing this on UI therad.

Try this:

public class Main extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread th = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        URL url=null;
                        url = new URL(et.getText().toString());
                        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                        String line = "";
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        tv.append(line);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };
        th.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!, this one worked just great!!
I'm guessing that it somehow connected to the previous guy's answer..

Comment: MM.. Well the point is that you need to do the internet stuff in Thread other than your main thread. :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i will suggest you to use [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Do this

On **ButtonClick**

```
RequestClient reqClient = new RequestClient(ActivityName.this);
String AppResponse = null;
AppResponse = reqClient.execute().get();
```

**RequestClient**

```
public class RequestClient extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // Create HTTP Client
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://yoururl.com"); // Set the action you want to do
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget); // Executeit
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
            InputStream is = entity.getContent(); // Create an InputStream with the response
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) // Read line by line
            sb.append(line + "\n");

            String resString = sb.toString(); // Result is here

            is.close(); // Close the stream
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_ERROR", "Error is " + e.toString());
        }
        Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC_RESPONSE", responseString.trim());
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        return responseString.trim();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```